# Remove sub title "the default view title" from the charts in dynamics 365

Tags: charts, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I want to remove the default view name from the chart placed on one of the Dashboard.
Please see the below image.

[image]

Comment: maybe through the xml?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, No, I have tried it.